# set_exception_handler tries to catch Error

Tags: php

Here is the code I use to catch at the global level missed exceptions and errors:

```
set_exception_handler( function( Exception $e ) {
    $exceptionCode = $e->getCode();

    switch ( $exceptionCode ) {
        case '42000': # Database
            FlashMessages::flashIt( 'message', 'There is a syntax error in the db query' );
            include( Settings::ABSPATH . '/src/views/message.php' );
            var_dump( $e );
            exit;
            break;
        default:
            FlashMessages::flashIt( 'message', 'Something unpredicted happened.' );
            include( Settings::ABSPATH . '/src/views/message.php' );
            var_dump( $e );
            exit;
            break;
    }
} );

set_error_handler( function( $errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    FlashMessages::flashIt( 'message', 'An error happened.' );
    include( Settings::ABSPATH . '/src/views/message.php' );
    var_dump( $errstr );
    exit;
} );
```

What I expected:
All exceptions caught by set_exception_handler.
All errors caught by set_error_handler.

What I have: set_exception_handler tries to catch errors and generate problems: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to {closure}() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given

set_error_handler doesn't catch this kind of error even if I completely remove the set_exception_handler.

Question: how can I catch from those global functions the kind of error that is missed by both of these function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change exception handler param type from `Exception` to `Throwable`.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php#refsect1-function.set-exception-handler-changelog